# Is it grammatical to switch verb tense in a predicate with a conjunction?

Tags: tenses, conjunctions

I am having a massive debate about whether the following sentence is grammatical:

> The tag was created and is printed.

The issue is the switch of tense between *was created* and *is printed*.  Some argue that this is invalid English because of the inconsistency of the tenses.  However, it seems to me that the presence of the conjunction *and* allows for this because *the tag* applies to both verb phrases and makes the above sentence a short hand form of something like:

> The tag was created.  It is printed.

It's possible that this is only the case with forms of *to be*, however, or perhaps just the passive.  For example, the following certainly ***does not*** seem grammatical:

> He threw the rock and catches the ball.

But there is a fundamental difference between the two examples, besides the forms of *to be*.  In the latter, the subject of the sentence is not also the object of the verb as it is in the sentence under question.  As such, such a shift in mentality with just a conjunction is not warranted.

It gets very confusing.  Is it grammatical to switch tenses in a predicate at all?  If so, under what circumstances?

Comment: Of course you can mix tenses, *if it makes sense*. For example, someone could say *"I was **baptised**, so I **know** I **will go** to heaven when I die"*. That's past, present, and future all validly used in one sentence. The question is Not Constructive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I grew up in Sydney and live in London*.  It’s hard to think of a more natural way to say this.  So, yes, it is grammatical to conjoin predicates in different tenses:  *it always was, still is, and ever will be.*

(*He catches the ball* and *It is printed* sound a bit weird out of context.  That may account for your wondering whether something is wrong with your initial sentences.  *He catches the ball* sounds like a primer sentence. *It is printed* might be better as *It has been printed*, but, without context, it’s hard to say.)

Comment: *He threw the rock and is catching the ball.*